# Best practices and code to upload image to firebase storage

Tags: android, image, file-upload, bitmap, firebase-storage

I have used 3 different codes to test the uploaded size of an image file to firebase storage. (Original size of image is 12.3 MB)

The **first** code converts the uri to bitmap and places it on an ImageView, compresses it the PNG format and finally uploads the image to firebase storage.

Uploaded format: .PNG. Size after upload: 14.82 MB.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("feed_photos").child(randomName);

            mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            byte[] data2 = outputStream.toByteArray();

            UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(data2);

            progressDialog.setMessage("uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "UPLOAD FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The **second** code does the same as the first, but converts it the JPEG instead.

Uploaded format .JPEG. Size after upload 5.58 MB.

Difference of second code to first:

`bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream); //JPEG this time!`

The **third** code directly uploads the image from the phone storage to firebase storage.

Uploaded format .JPEG. Size after upload 3.41 MB.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("feed_photos").child(randomName);

            UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(uri);

            progressDialog.setMessage("uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "UPLOAD FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
```

After uploading, I compared the three images from firebase storage, and there does not seem to be any difference between the quality of the three images. This raises the question of why upload in PNG at all when a smaller image size of JPEG will do (Q1)? Also, even the smallest file size of 3.41 MB is also quite large especially if the app has a large user base that uploads images regularly. In this case, what is the commonly accepted image size to be stored that maintains an image quality comparable to say, Whatsapp (Q2).

Also, in the third code, I did not write any code for compression. However, it seems that it uploads with the smallest image size anyway. So why do tutorials border to even compress the images in the first place (Q3)? (original image size is 12.3 MB)

These questions confused me as what code and best practices should I use to upload an image to firebase storage.

What I want my app to do (Main Question):

The user selects the image from the phone's image gallery, the image pops onto an ImageView so that the user may add a title to it as a metadata. When the user confirms, the image along with its metadata is uploaded to firebase storage. The quality of the image on the ImageView and after download may be comparable to Whatsapp's images. Hence, what is the proper code and best practices to achieve this? It would be helpful if the first 3 questions (Q1, 2 and 3) were answered first before the Main Question. Sorry for this as I am new to android development and is self-learning. Thanks in advance!

Extra: I have not talked about downloading the image from firebase storage, but I plan to use firebaseui with glide to do it. Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

1)A PNG is lossless.  A jpg is lossy compression.  That means that a PNG can be exactly decoded to the original image, a jpg cannot (data, and thus quality, is lost in compression).  If you have a file you want to maintain at top quality, you need PNG.  Please note that depending on the Q factor you saved the jpg with and the type of image, you may not see a visible quality difference.

2)You saved it as JPG and PNG.  THose are compressed file formats already.  A fully decompressed bmp file is even bigger.

3)What Q factor does upload task save the data with?  My guess is fairly low.  Which is fine for some types of images.  But the lower the Q factor, the smaller the file (but the bigger the loss in compression).  Without knowing that, you aren't comparing equal things.

Comment: But why are my manually compressed JPEG and PNG images larger than the JPEG I uploaded directly from my gallery storage? Is this because of Q factor? I do not quite understand this.

Comment: DId you use the same Q factor for the compression with you manual ones than the one you let it compress?  A PNG being bigger, even much bigger than a JPG is expected-  lossless compression is bigger than lossy of the same data.  ALso, did you compress the same original image or did you uncompress and recompress (with JPG this would actually change the image each time, as lossy compression of lossy compression leads to even more data loss).

Comment: I chose the same image each time from storage. That's all I know. Also, I do not know what or how to use Q factor.

Comment: Q factor is the quantization factor, ascaling quality factor, a value between 1 and 100.  The higher it is, the more accurate the jpg is (but the bigger the file).  In itmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);  its the middle variable.  An example of an image at different Qs and resultant size can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: As you can see from my third code, I did not touch the Q factor. So if the image uploaded with a smaller JPEG size, does that mean the Q factor is not 100? However, when I compare them, there is no quality difference to my eyes.

Comment: Sometime there isn't a big difference.  It depends on what the image is of, and how nice it plays with the compression algorithm (which is math above my paygrade to explain).  But yes, if a JPG magically jumped from 12 MB to 3MB, it was recompressed at a higher compression rate.  There's no other way for that to happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152588/discussion-between-ben-and-gabe-sechan).